# How add a style in qweb only if a qweb var is true, without duplicate the code?

Tags: css, odoo, qweb

I want output 20 td with a css style depends on a qweb var.
Is where any alternative to duplicate the whole code like this:

```
<table>
...
<td>
<t t-if="line_odd">
  <td class="padding-top"><p t-esc="line.field1">...</td>
...
  <td class="padding-top"><p t-esc="line.field20" />...</td>
</td>

<t t-if="not line_odd">
  <p class="no-padding-top"><p t-esc="line.field1">...</td>
...
  <p class="no-padding-top"><p t-esc="line.field20">...</td>
</td>
```

because this code isn't valid 
a)

```
<tr>
  <t t-if="line_odd">
     <td class="padding-top">
  </t>
  <t t-if="not line_odd">
     <td class="padding-top">
  </t>
     <p>...</p>
  </td>
</td>
```

b)

```
<td <t t-if="true">class='padding-top'</t> >
   <p>...</p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `t-att-class` or `t-attf-class` if you need to combine default strings:

```
<td t-att-class="line_odd and 'no-padding' or 'padding-top'">

<td t-attf-class="foo #{line_odd and 'no-padding' or 'padding-top'}">
```

See [docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html#reference-qweb-attributes).